# libtiff version of OpenCV 2.3.1

Tags: opencv, libtiff

OpenCV 2.3.1 uses libtiff as 3rd party library.
And I want to know which version of libtiff is used for a security reason.
But libtiff source code in opencv dose not show a version.

What is libtiff version of OpenCV 2.3.1?
Or is there any list of 3rd party libraries`s version for opencv ?

Comment: Yes, right in the [readme](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/2.3.1/3rdparty/readme.txt#L23)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize how to figure out it.

I do share the information.

check it out from
opencv-2.3.1\3rdparty\tiffvers.h

Version is written in that file.